# What's the most remote place in the contiguous US?

Tags: united-states, backcountry, wilderness

The United States is a very developed place. Sometimes this can prove to be challenging when trying to find a place to get away from everything, especially east of the Mississippi where I reside. I am pretty sure the answer is likely somewhere western (Montana maybe), but **what is the most remote place in the contiguous US**?

So let's define *remote*:

- Furthest distance from civilization or any signs of it including anything man-made like roads, forest service facilities, huts/shelters...
- Furthest distance from medical care or rescue if something goes wrong; difficult terrain could trump the distance.
- Number of visitors recorded? Or other USFS data...
- Essentially, no visible traces of humans, or "untouched" if that's even possible these days.

*Now, I know this could seem like an opinionated question to some folks, but I'm really looking for places that can be backed up and grounded with as much factual data as possible.*

**Edit:** *I previously said "continental" US, when the correct term is "contiguous." Oops. Please bear that in mind regarding my comments below.*

Comment: I need to source it, but there is a trail in Yellowstone, in the south part of the park, wherein at one point you are 36 miles from any road whatsoever. That is the furthest from civilization anywhere in the lower 48.

Comment: Your message implies that you want to visit a place like this. What you have to understand is that a TRULY remote place like this will not be survivable for long. You probably couldn't carry enough water over the terrain that you would be required to cross to get there in the first place. Even if the ONLY thing you carried was water, and nothing else, you couldn't stay in the remote places very long

Comment: Yes, my question does imply that by my introduction, but that isn't necessarily what I'm wanting to know. Maybe I should re-word that. I don't necessarily want to visit whatever may be the most remote location, depending on what that location is. I really just want to know what's the most inaccessible location in the States? (not including the obvious Alaska, which is not _continental_)

Comment: @AffableGeek - I would love to know what that trail is.

Comment: Wouldn't the criteria of "furthest distance from anything man made" disqualify any trail?

Comment: Technically, yes. Still would be good info though.

Comment: @manoftheson If you wish it 'get away from  everything' perhaps it would be sufficient to simply feel remote. The Northeast has plenty of areas where human travel is light. Larger states in the Southeast would too, I would expect. Dense vegetation helps, but there may be an occasional airplane to spoil the illusion.

Comment: Marfa, Texas maybe. Google it. West Texas. No major towns (heading west) for 500 miles.

Comment: I like your question and it is interesting to ask precisely because it makes you realize how little wild, in a way, there's left. But if you just want remote, cross the border & go north, you'll find...

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it was only useful for a moment in time. It lacks lasting value, making it a bad example of an SE question. Much of the information is obsolete. The map in the accepted answer is incorrect. Cell phone coverage, population density and electrical power-line coverages have changed. When posted, the two Wikipedia links had notices that they were missing resources, and they still do. I feel that closing it would discourage similar questions.

Comment: @Sue - So shouldn’t the answer be updated then instead of closing the question? If you don’t see value in the question, then feel free to contribute edits to make it more valuable.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Project Remote was started by a scientifically-minded couple to quantitatively determine the most remote locations in each of the 50 states mainly using the distance to the nearest road or town and whether cel phone coverage is available. They've cataloged quite a few states already east of the Mississippi, which you can check out here: [Project Remote](http://remotefootprints.org/project-remote). The caveat is that the exact coordinates are kept secret to protect the area's remoteness, although the general location is specified.

Here is a map of what they found. Each documented state (light green) has a pretty extensive report of the area, along with distance to nearest road, cel phone coverage, and accessibility issues:
[image]

Here are the states with the most remote spots discovered so far:

1. **Montana**: 18.0 miles from nearest road, no cel coverage
2. **Idaho**: 17.6 miles from nearest road, no cel coverage
3. **Florida**: 17.0  miles from nearest road, no cel coverage
4. **Minnesota**: 14.3 miles from nearest road, no cel coverage

Comment: I think we might have a winner! This is pretty much exactly the type of thing I was looking for. And so far, it looks like my casual mention of Montana was a good guess.

Comment: This sounds really cool, I wonder if there's a project like this in Canada, one that preferably excludes the parts of Canada that are permanently frozen...

Comment: I heard about the project from a podcast awhile ago--it's an interesting story: https://soundcloud.com/thedirtbagdiaries/the-remotest

Comment: The remotest spot in Arizona looks suspiciously close to Page.

Comment: I can't tell for sure but it appears these don't include national parks yes?

Comment: Scale in Canada is much bigger. Attawapiskat is 200km from it's northern neighbour, with nothing man-made in the middle. And that's without leaving Ontario.

Comment: I find it surprising that it's so little - in the UK we think of the US as containing vast wilderness and desert areas but if this is right you're never more than a days walk from a road.

In the UK we have an official figure from the Ordinance Survey - it's grid reference NH02020 77000 in the Letterewe forest in North-West Scotland, 6.48 miles from the road (but much farther to hike as it's seriously rough country).

Comment: Related BBC article about same [Where is the remotest spot in the United States?](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-42104894)

Answer (score 17):

The answer to your question is: the middle of the Selway-Bitteroot/River-of-No-Return Wildnerness in Idaho. These are actually two wilderness areas joined together (separated by a single dirt road) which together form the largest roadless area and the largest wildnerness in the Continental US. The Selway Bitterroot is where the author of "A River Runs Through It" spent his youth as a Forest Ranger. If you look on a electrical power-line map of the United States, you see a huge area in Idaho in which powerlines are completely absent, the largest such area devoid of electrical transmission lines in the continental US.

[image]

These mountain areas are also known for thwarting the Lewis and Clark expedition due to how rugged they are.

[River of No Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Church%E2%80%94River_of_No_Return_Wilderness)

[Selway Bitterroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selway-Bitterroot_Wilderness)

Answer (score 12):

Most of the "untouched" places left in North America are that way for a reason, no one wants to touch them. There are loads of barren desserts in Nevada, Utah, New Mexico and Arizona that people don't bother going to because it's dead, there's nothing there but heat sand and rocks.

The easiest way to figure out what parts of the USA are isolated from people, is to look at a cell phone coverage map. Those white areas, there aren't many people living there. Some of them are **National Forests**, some are **deserts**, others are **reserves**. The hard thing to find would be an area that doesn't have any roads or tracks going through it. Even the most barren of desserts typically have a freeway to get you to the other side. Looking at different Human Geography maps will give you a broad idea of which parts of the country are most isolated. You can then do some region specific research to find out more about what makes those area so isolated. The only truly large wild country is in the Canada part of the USA, up in Alaska.

**Cell Phone Coverage**
[image]

**Population Density**
[image]

**Point population density**
[Interactive version here](http://luminocity3d.org/WorldPopDen/#4/42.03/-98.61)
[image]

**[Roads](http://www.tripinfo.com/maps/USA.htm)**
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I intentionally said 'continental US' because Alaska is a no brainer answer if you say just 'US.' And if you broaden the question to North America, then Canada is a shoe-in for have the most remote place.

Comment: Depending on where you are there may be some "untouched" Canadian wilderness a lot closer to you than the US areas.

Answer (score 3):

Northern Maine, there's a stretch of the Appalachian Trail nicknamed the hundred mile wilderness, I don't believe I seen a soul for at least 3 days

Answer (score 2):

Absaroka Mountain range in Wyoming right next to the trident plateau. National Geographic named it the most remote place in the lower 48. I lived there for 29 days, backpacking with NOLS... it's doable, trust me, and by far the most secluded section of wilderness I have ever set foot in.

Comment: Existing answers have much more support for their answers.  Can you include a link to your reference and supporting reasons for the rating?